# SQL server - job calling procedure and procedure difference

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create table from view from remote server (calling procedure UPDATE_PROC), like this:

```
SELECT  *
INTO    table
FROM    [remote_server\database].DATABASE.dbo.view
```

And it works perfectly. 
Problem is, when I try to create a new job, which is calling the previously worked stored procedure UPDATE_PROC

```
exec UPDATE_PROC
```

It doesn't work and reports:

```
Executed as user: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM. The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "remote_server\database" does not contain the table ""DATABASE"."dbo"."view"". The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 7314).  The step failed
```

So it seems to be same, but it isn't. What I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Remote server is SQL Server 2005, job is on SQL Server 2008

I'm logged as **sa** user. Procedure is working always, job calling stored procedure never

Job isn't run as sa user, but I don't know which user and where should be defined to execute the job propery....

Comment: What user were you running the first query as? Looks like the job is running as the local system user - who I doubt has permissions on the remote server.

Comment: I'm trying it sa user. Procedure is working always, job calling procedure never

Comment: @gaffcz Yes you said - but the job you've created to run the procedure is not running as sa, it's running as the windows local system user. Please see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187910.aspx), and try altering the job step - setting "Run As" to the sa SQL Server user.

Comment: I'm just spitballing here (and it's not really going to answer your question), but you do know that `UPDATE` is a [reserved word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238507(v=sql.80).aspx), right? As such, I don't think that there can be any guarantees as to how something will behave when you name an object after a reserved word. For future DBAs, devs, and audits, it may be nice to have a more descriptive name for your stored procedure.

Comment: nj, I have very different situation on the server server, this is only wrong named example for this purposes :-) I'll rename it

Comment: finally, problem is somewhere in installation of job agent, because it doesn't work properly. On the next sql server, everything is OK....:/

Comment: What account(s) are your SQL Service and SQL Agent Service running?

Comment: Local system account, both of them. But it seems i haven't properly uninstalled the previous version of sql server 2005 and there are also its dead services (agent and sqlserver). I have some mess there, I've noticed it now :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that's a security issue. User under which the job is running doesn't have permissions to access table on the remote server.

Comment: Yop, but I'm sa user and procedure itself is working always...:(

Comment: @gaffcz When you run it from the SSMS you're 'sa' (that's working for you), but the job is running under NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM which is your local windows user.

Comment: finally, problem is somewhere in installation of job agent, because it doesn't work properly. On the next sql server, everything is OK....:/